# Eigenvalues - What does it mean that matrix $A$ is "scaling space" by $\lambda_i$ in direction $\mathbf v^{(i)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [Deep Learning (page 44)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/deep-learning) it is stated that:

> Specifically, every real symmetric matrix can be decomposed into an expression using only real-valued eigenvectors and eigenvalues:
>   $$\mathbf A = \mathbf {Q Λ Q^T}$$
>   where $\mathbf Q$ is an orthogonal matrix composed of eigenvectors of $\mathbf A$, and $\mathbf Λ$ is a diagonal matrix. The eigenvalue $Λ_{i,i}$ is associated with the eigenvector in column $i$ of $\mathbf Q$, denoted as $\mathbf Q_{:,i}$.
>   Because $\mathbf Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, we can think of $\mathbf A$ as scaling space by $λ_i$ in direction $\mathbf v^{(i)}$.

What does it mean that matrix $A$ is *scaling space* by $\lambda_i$ in direction $\mathbf v^{(i)}$?

Comment: The matrix $A=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&3}$, or the function $f(x,y)=(2x,3y)$, are scaling space in the direction of the $x$-axis by a factor of $2$, and scaling space in the direction of the $y$-axis by a factor of $3$. If you can understand this, you can understand the quoted passage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to motivate the notion of eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix $\mathbf A$ is to ask whether there are any lines that are left fixed by $\mathbf A$. If $\mathbf v$ is any vector on such a line, linearity requires that we have $\mathbf{Av}=\lambda\mathbf v$, where $\lambda$ is some fixed scalar. This equation is the defining equation for eigenvectors and eigenvalues: a non-zero vector that satisfies this equation is called an eigenvector (characteristic vector) of $\mathbf A$ and the corresponding scalar $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue (characteristic value). Geometrically, this equation can be interpreted as saying that in the direction defined by $\mathbf v$, the action of $\mathbf A$ is particularly simple: it’s just scaling by $\lambda$.

Comment: The last passage is key. Thanks